# Equally spaced Flex layout, centred and going to both ends

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm struggling to achieve something I thought would be fairly straightforward with flexbox, where I have 5 elements on a row - I want the first and last items to be at the start and end of the container, then the other 3 items should be equally spaced, with the 3rd item centred and underneath the item above it in my example. The issue here, I think, is that the 3rd and 4th items are nested together inside two parent divs. I don't have the option of changing the HTML structure unfortunately, so I'm trying to work around it, to no avail so far. Any advice on how best to possibly tackle this would be much appreciated.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top-parent {
width: 40%;
}

.sub-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.full-width .item {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <a class="full-width">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </a>
    <span class="item"></span>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="top-parent">
      <div class="sub-parent">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want all six boxes in the same row?? Just to be sure. If you can attach an image, about how final boxes should look, it would be nice

Comment: Also, are all the items the exact same width as in that example here? Otherwise, _“with the 3rd item centred”_ might require extra work.

Comment: @AKNair The first item is intended to be on its own, centred above the 5 below it.

Comment: The items are all the same width and height, 30px by 30px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, you can change one of the CSS properties like this -

```
.sub-parent {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Tried that before and double checked there, but it doesn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: Created a codepen link. Check here - https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/RwaqLjK